# A Python virtual environment ends up with an older version of PIP than the one that created it... why and how can I fix this versioning issue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, installation, virtualenv

My question is similar to another that was asked about [Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689514/why-python3-m-venv-myenv-installs-older-version-of-pip-into-myenv-than-any-ve) so perhaps the answer is the same one - if so, I´d appreciate it if somebody can clarify this and go the step further of answering the additional questions posted here since there is, really, not a good answer there as to WHY it happens and HOW to avoid it without unintended consequences. Perhaps with 2.7 there is a better one?

I don´t understand the following sequence where a virtual environment in my MAC OS ends up with a version of PIP that´s older than the version it created it:

```
dhcp--41:VO$ virtualenv -p 
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/python env
Running virtualenv with interpreter 
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/python
New python executable in /Users/jbs/PycharmProjects/VOSW- VWN/env/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/jbs/PycharmProjects/VOSW-VWN/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

We´ve made sure the interpreter is 2.7.15

```
dhcp--41:VO$ source env/bin/activate
(env) dhcp--41:VO jbs$ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, May  1 2018, 16:44:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

This is just a check that the interpreter is 2.7.15 and now we generate the requirements output which is small as expected but which gives this warning (which is what I DON´T understand):

```
(env) dhcp--41:VO$ pip freeze
wheel==0.26.0
You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

We´ll now leave the environment and do freeze outside it:

```
(env) dhcp--41:VO$ deactivate
dhcp--41:VO$ pip freeze
absl-py==0.2.0
```

No suggestion for upgrade is given here despite the fact that we have the SAME version of python (if I understand correctly) as we check next:

```
dhcp-18--41:VO$ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, May  1 2018, 16:44:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Why did it install a different version of pip? Or perhaps, why does it default to a different version inside the virtual environment? It seems very odd to me. How can I make sure this does not happen every time I create a new virtual environment? Any input would be most helpful!

Comment: Can we see `pip --version`, `which pip` and the first line of the `pip` script? It could be a different Python.

Comment: Following phd, check your venv's python version with (env) $ which python

Comment: which pip outside the environment: /usr/local/bin/pip. pip --version outside the environment pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7). Once the environment is made: which pip is
    /Users/jbs/PycharmProjects/WakeUpTEST/env/bin/pip. And pip --version inside the environment:
    pip 8.0.2 from /Users/jbs/PycharmProjects/WakeUpTEST/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: Thanks mdn, @phd for your interest, to finish answering your questions with the second ones, in the environment we get: which python is
/Users/jbs/PycharmProjects/WakeUpTEST/env/bin/python . And 
python --version is Python 2.7.15.

Comment: Dupe: [Why 'python3 -m venv myenv' installs older version of pip into myenv than any version of pip I can find anywhere on the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29689514/674039)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why 'python3 -m venv myenv' installs older version of pip into myenv than any version of pip I can find anywhere on the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689514/why-python3-m-venv-myenv-installs-older-version-of-pip-into-myenv-than-any-ve)

Answer (score 2):

Your `pip` outside virtual environment is `/usr/local/bin/pip` which most probably means it uses `/usr/local/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python`. But you've created the virtual environment using a different python — `/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/python`. You can check its `pip` version with

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/pip --version
```

or

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/python -m pip --version
```

To upgrade that `pip` you need to run

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/python -m pip install -U pip
```

And to upgrade `pip` inside the virtual env

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

after activating  the virtual env.

Comment: python -m pip install -U pip does upgrade pip to 10.0.1 in the virtualenvironment. However the version of pip in the Cellar directory is 10.0.1 (checked how you suggested it) while in creating the virtual environment still the version 8.0.2 is the one that shows up... so this presents a way to solve the issue once but does not explain why it happens in the first place nor how to avoid it in future cases... any hint would be most welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

## Newer

If you want to "hotpatch" your installed python, just modify the versions listed in `ensurepip/__init__.py` and replace the two files in `ensurepip/_bundled`. You can find this location by running `find * | grep ensurepip` from the directory where python is installed. On macOS with Homebrew, this is the location: `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ensurepip`

You will also want to delete the `ensurepip/__pycache__` directory that contains the `.pyc` files.

## My older, build-time fix:

You are able to update the bundled versions of pip and setuptools by patching Python before building it from source. The following patch will update the bundled versions of pip and setuptools to the current available today. You will want to invoke `configure` with the following option: `--with-ensurepip=upgrade`

Those `whl` files are downloaded from PYPI here:

https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files

https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#files

```
diff -ru Python-3.7.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py Python-3.7.1.new/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py
--- Python-3.7.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py  2018-10-20 06:04:19.000000000 +0000
+++ Python-3.7.1.new/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py  2018-11-27 02:36:19.301655008 +0000
@@ -8,9 +8,9 @@
 __all__ = ["version", "bootstrap"]


-_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION = "39.0.1"
+_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION = "40.6.2"

-_PIP_VERSION = "10.0.1"
+_PIP_VERSION = "18.1"

 _PROJECTS = [
     ("setuptools", _SETUPTOOLS_VERSION),
Only in Python-3.7.1/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled: pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Only in Python-3.7.1.new/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled: pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Only in Python-3.7.1/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled: setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Only in Python-3.7.1.new/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled: setuptools-40.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Instead of posting the same answer on two different questions, you should flag one of them as a duplicate of the other. I know you don't have the permission to do this yourself, but you can use the general flagging option below the question to bring it to a mod's attention.

Comment: Thanks. I've just flagged it. Should I delete this answer? Also, thanks for the tips!!

Answer (score -1):

you can type this command

```
pip install --disable-pip-version-check upgrade_ensurepip
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.